# How long does it take for a newly registered user to be allowed to use WeChat on web?

Tags: chat, registration, wechat

Apparently, newly registered users cannot use the WeChat web application. Trying to log in by scanning a QR-code gives the following message: <sup>(*)</sup>

> For account security, newly registered WeChat accounts are unable to log in to Web WeChat. To use WeChat on a computer, use Windows WeChat or Mac WeChat at http://wechat.com

How long does it take for a new user to be able to use the web version?

<sup>(*)</sup> Note: the notification may be absent when trying to log in via a third party Google Chrome application (or other)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can translate **"newly created accounts"** to **"accounts created after June 2017"** – it seems they've basically grandfathered the web client, you'll never be allowed to log in to the WeChat for web unless you obtain an old account or they change this policy.

Source: https://github.com/Chatie/wechaty/issues/872

Comment: The very same thread now suggests there is a fix for this issue...

Answer (score 2):

There is no use, I got an account earlier than June 2017.
It wont let me login and state that "for your safety you're not allowed to log in web"
I think they are just forcing people to download actual application on pc for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

My account is about 2 years old and is identity verified.
I still get this message if I try to use web chat.

I somehow think the message should be regarded as "Web Client WeChat is no longer supported"

Comment: Interestingly, I do see (chinese) users use wechat online at wx.qq.com, while I get the same error message.

Comment: No laowai allowed on the web version ahahaha