# How long does one have to wait to be able to connect to web.wechat.com?

Tags: wechat

When trying to connect to connect to web.wechat.com, I get the error message:

> For account security, newly registered WeChat accounts are unable to log in to WeChat for Web. To use WeChat on a computer, you can download WeChat for Windows or WeChat for Mac at http://wechat.com

[image]

How long does one have to wait to be able to connect to web.wechat.com? (not to be considered as a newly registered WeChat account anymore)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long does it take for a newly registered user to be allowed to use WeChat on web?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/117203/how-long-does-it-take-for-a-newly-registered-user-to-be-allowed-to-use-wechat-on)

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://github.com/liangjfblue/wxBot4g/issues/1) seems to imply accounts made after 2018 will never be able to.